# Saving data in external json file using for phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

Here is the json file:

```
{
    "person":[{
        "names": "Shay",
        "age": 27
    },
    {
        "names": "Nats",
        "age": 21
        }]
}
```

Here is the jquery code

```
$(document).on("click","#btns", function(){
        var url = "../trial.json";
        $.getJSON(url, function(data){
            var item = {names: "Cha", age: 23}
            data.person.push(item);
            var newJson = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log(newJson);
        });
    });
```

How can i save the new data in the external JSON file??

Comment: Send data to server and rewrite the file there

Comment: can I get the code for this ??

Comment: This isn't a free code writing service and we have no idea what server side programming language you are using

Comment: sorry cause i badly need the code for my final year project and am using only html css and javascript for my application using the phonegap platform. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Might consider using a cloud data storage service such as firebase instead